# WordPress Multisite - Change Main Site from no-www to www

Tags: ssl, wordpress, www

I've started issuing automated `wildcard SSL-Certificates` over the `acme-dns-client`.
While having an easy way to cover all of my subdomains together, I'm having the issue to not have, any coverage for my no-www domain.

Therefore I thought it could be an good idea, to just `change the no-www Mainsite` to `www.example.net` instead of `example.net`

---

> Does anyone has suggestions how to change these settings, because they
> are not available into the Wordpress Multisite Admin Dashboard, here
> you can just change the subdomains for subpages.

---

I've already tried to just add following line into the `wp-config.php`.

```
define('WP_HOME','https://www.example.net');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.example.net');
```

But this didn't worked out yet. I'm using nginx as my root webserver system.

---

**Nginx Config**

```
server {
   location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {
                         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                         fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
             fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
                 fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
                 fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
            }

            location ~ /\.ht {
                         deny all;
            }

            location = /favicon.ico {
                         log_not_found off;
                         access_log off;
            }

            location = /robots.txt {
                         allow all;
                         log_not_found off;
                         access_log off;
           }

            location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                         expires max;
                         log_not_found off;
           }

        root /var/www/wordpress;
        index index.php;

        server_name example.net www.example.net get.example.net *.example.net;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    #settings for file upload
    client_max_body_size 32M;
}

server {
    if ($host = example.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;

        server_name example.net *.example.net;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to have WordPress determine which URL to serve, but for nginx you will need to post your current configuration.

Comment: i dont know, how you think about the future of www on a url, already been since years it has became the standard that www is not more required and furthermore it is not more shown... 